# Using legacy storage in Android API29

Tags: android, storage, android-10.0

I am trying to use "Legacy Storage" for my app so that it can run on API29, as a temporary measure until I can understand the new storage model. I have set

> requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

in the manifest, but it still doesn't work. The Android docs say:

> **Test scoped storage**
>
> To enable scoped storage in your app, regardless
> of your app's target SDK version and manifest flag values, enable the
> following app compatibility flags:
>
> DEFAULT_SCOPED_STORAGE (enabled for all apps by default)
> FORCE_ENABLE_SCOPED_STORAGE (disabled for all apps by default)
>
> To disable scoped storage and use the legacy storage model instead, unset both flags.

**How** do I unset the flags? Any other advice?

Comment: What's your target SDK and what device are you running on?

Comment: TargetSdk and compileSdk are both 29. I am trying to run it on a Nexus5X API29 emulator in Android studio. The app runs OK on a Nexus5X API28 emulator and on a Sony Xperia phone running API28

Comment: Forget those docs. requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" is all you need to continue using external storage as before. Of course it will work unless you had set it to false before. In that case deinstall your app. Then reinstall.

Comment: I do have   requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"   in the manifest, but the app fails on the statement   request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir  . As I say, this runs OK on API28 emulator/device.

Comment: When I say "fails", I mean a runtime error. The app builds OK.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question to include a [mcve]. That would include the complete stack trace, along with the source code that is triggering the stack trace.

Comment: If you are using DownloadManager then you even do not need requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" .

Comment: That was really helpful - thank you. It has shown me that my problem is not what I thought it was!

Comment: One problem was that I had put requestLegacyExternalStorage+"true" in my Manifest in the <Permission.../> section. It should have been in the <application.../> section. 

That hasn't cured all my file I/O problems with API29, but it has helped.

Answer (score 3):

Back to the main question:

> How do I unset the flags? Any other advice?

The flags you mention (DEFAULT_SCOPED_STORAGE and FORCE_ENABLE_SCOED_STORAGE) are for development purpouse only. You can set them in **App Compatibility Changes** panel on settings. To find this pannel, you have to unlock **Developer options** in settings and you can find  there **App Compatibility Changes**.

For more information, see the documentation: [How to identify which changes are enabled](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/test-changes#identify)

Answer (score 0):

At last (with more research on stackoverflow!) I have found the way around my problem, so I'll describe it here in case it is of help to anyone else.

THE APP WORKS OK UP TO API28:

My app downloads a file called myfile.txt and saves it in external memory, using DownloadManager. The directory where DownloadManager saves it is determined by

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("","myfile.txt");
```

which returns the directory path`/storage/emulated/0`

When I read the file, I get the directory to read from using

```
String myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

which returns the same directory path. This works OK up to API28.

THE PROBLEM:

For API29, I put

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in the `<application....../>` section of the manifest, but even then `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` doesn't work - it crashes with a runtime error.

THE ANSWER THAT WORKED FOR ME:

Instead of `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` I used

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,"","myfile,txt");
```

which works OK in API29 and also the earlier versions. However, it returns a different directory path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.barney.aboutmyjourney/files` (com.barney/aboutmyjourney is my app).

To get the directory path when reading the file, I therefore used

```
File myFile=this.getExternalFilesDir("myfile.txt");
String myPath=myFile.getParent();
```

which returns the path I want (`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.barney.aboutmyjourney/files`).

This now works for me. Now just lots of slog modifying all my file IO. Perhaps I should just understand and used Scoped Storage instead!